# Eloquent paginate breaks on 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am receiving the following error when using paginate with Eloquent:

`Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Pagination\Factory::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\View\Factory, instance of Illuminate\View\Environment given, called in C:\****\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider.php on line 23 and defined`

For testing purposes, this is all I have in the method of my controller:

```
return User::paginate(15);
```

I'm aware about the upgrade procedure from the docs, but I don't have any of the references mentioned there.

**Update:**

In my specific case there was a package in the workbench which was requiring Illuminate 4.1 components, I changed to 4.2 in composer.json, removed the vendor dir and composer.lock file, did a composer install, and the error is gone.

These operations were all done within the package folder.

Comment: Is there any chance you are only requiring some of the Laravel components, and not the entire Laravel framework? If you are only working with some then things like this can get out of whack, especially if not all of your components are updated to 4.2.

Comment: Hi Mr. Sturgeon, your comment made me inspect the workbench, there was a package requiring 4.1, I updated to 4.2 and the error is gone now.

Comment: Tadaaaaa! Dependencies are a fun game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posted as a comment, but it was the right answer:

> Is there any chance you are only requiring some of the Laravel components, and not the entire Laravel framework? If you are only working with some then things like this can get out of whack, especially if not all of your components are updated to 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as you when I updated from 4.1 to 4.2, which in my case I did a composer update on my development environment before pushing and did a pull from my staging. Now the pagination issue doesn't exist in my development but in my staging, so I figured it might be the issue with git pull missed some files, or cache in the views. So I did remove the entire project and do a clean clone from the repository, that seems to fix the problem.

So not fully sure on how you update, but you might want to check that your updated files has been fully applied.

Comment: I had a similar situation when upgrading from 4.0 to 4.1, but it wasn't the case this time. Fortunately if a google search ends here, the user will have two possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this same problem when upgrading from 4.1 to 4.2, but my fix was different to Phil Sturgeon's.

I simply had to remove the `bootstrap/compiled.php` file located in the root of the Laravel project.